HowTo create correct access mapping for PWA?
I'm using SharePoint Server 2019 as a platform for Project Server 2019 (PWA). There is three PWA: mc-prj01.mydomain.com:80, mc-prj01.mydomain.com:8080 and mc-prj01.mydomain.com:8081 on my server. Servers are accessible from corporate LAN only, no internet access.
Now my access mapping table is:
Internal URL                           Zone         External URL
http://mc-prj01.mydomain.com:80/       Internet     http://mc-prj01.mydomain.com:80/
http://mc-prj01:80/                    Default      http://mc-prj01:80/
and the same for 8080,8081 and 16000 ports (I can't use https according to corporate rules)/
The PWA's are working correctly. But I got warnings in Event Viewer about wrong access mapping for all four ports like this:
Alternate access mappings have not been configured. Users or services are accessing the site http://mc-prj01.mydomain.com/ with the URL http://mc-prj01/
Looks like some mistakes in access mapping.
Please, how can I correctly write mapping and remove this annoying warnings?
